# How to create alert when two fields contain data

Tags: javascript, function, alert

I have two fields (A and B) on an application that cannot both contain data at the same time.  I would like for when someone has filled A, and then starts to fill B (and/or vice versa), an error message is thrown that tells them both fields cannot contain data.

I tried using javascript to throw an error onchange if both fields do not equal null, but haven't had success. I know this is an unsophisticated way to meet my intentions as well.

```
  <script>
//set IDs of selectors to use
var HighSchoolID = "ctl00$mainContent$CreateAccountUserControl$CreateUserControl$ProspectForm$datatel_highschoolacademichistoryd4d7c0cb_3dfc_451f_b497_62f37d538e48datatel_highschoolid$criteriaSchoolName" 
var UnlistedSchoolID = "ctl00$mainContent$CreateAccountUserControl$CreateUserControl$ProspectForm$datatel_highschoolacademichistoryd4d7c0cb_3dfc_451f_b497_62f37d538e48datatel_unlistedschoolinfo$datatel_unlistedschoolinfo" 
//attach OnChange event listener to fields
var HighSchool = document.getElemntByID(HighSchoolID);
var UnlistedSchool = document.getElementByID(UnlistedSchoolID);

  confirmHighSchool.addEventListener("click",CheckUnlisted);

  function CheckUnlisted(){
      if(HighSchool != null && UnlistedSchool != null){
          alert(ERROR);
      }
  }
  </script>
```

I would like for an error message to pop up when someone begins (or finishes, either work) filling out the second field.

Edit* Apologies, newbie on stackoverflow, more code included.  The two fields come delivered as part of our CRM, and it is required that one or the other is filled out.

Comment: Add more code. We have no clue what HighSchool or UnlistedSchool are.

Comment: A better user experience would be to set the field you don't want them to use as `readonly`

Comment: What about this isn't working? And what is `confirmHighSchool` ?

Comment: I modified a functional script to build this, so the confirmHighSchool is somewhat of an arbitrary name that I didn't change much from the original.  I apologize but I'm very new to javascript and am unfamiliar in writing my own scripts without taking pieces from already functioning pieces.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes.
**getElemntByID** is not a function,
neither is **getElementByID**

The correct function is [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Despite this, you need to check the value of your [inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) 
not the references of the inputs.

> As you stated you're new to javascript, I recommend you this link too: 
>   [w3schools examples about forms/inputs and validation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

checkout this fiddle:

```js
var highSchool = document.getElementById("highSchool");
var unlistedSchool = document.getElementById("unlistedSchool");
var confirmHighSchool = document.getElementById('confirmHighSchool');
  
confirmHighSchool.addEventListener("click", checkUnlisted);

function checkUnlisted() {
      if(highSchool.value && unlistedSchool.value){
          alert("ERROR MESSAGE TO BE ADDED");
      }
}
```

```html
 
<label for"highSchool" >HighSchool</label>
<input type="text" id="highSchool">
<br>
<label for"unlistedSchool" >UnlistedSchool</label>
<input type="text" id="unlistedSchool">
<br>
<button id="confirmHighSchool">Confirm Highschool</button>
```